# MySql query only if selected value has the newest Date

Tags: mysql, date

I need a special query for MySql. This is my actual query:

```
SELECT t.accountingClerk, t.creationDate. u.windowsAccountName, t.customer, c.lastName, c.firstName, c.assignee 
FROM ticket as t 
LEFT JOIN customer AS c on t.customer = c.customerId 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON c.assignee = u.emailAdress 
WHERE c.assignee IS NOT NULL AND t.accountingClerk = 'user1@mail.com'
GROUP BY t.customer;
```

The query works fine so far but the result is not exactly what I need. There are two possible matching tickets, a newer with "user2@mail.com" and an older one with user1@mail.com as accountingClerk. I need my query to show me the result only if the 'user1@mail.com" is the accountingClerk of the ticket with the newest creationDate.

I hope you guys understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for my problem:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempDateSort AS (SELECT accountingClerk, creationDate, customer FROM ticket ORDER BY creationDate DESC);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempCustomerGroup AS (SELECT * FROM tempDateSort GROUP BY customer);
SELECT t.accountingClerk, u.windowsAccountName, t.customer, c.lastName, c.firstName, c.assignee FROM tempCustomerGroup AS t 
LEFT JOIN customer AS c on t.customer = c.customerId 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON c.assignee = u.emailAdress 
WHERE c.assignee IS NOT NULL AND t.accountingClerk = 'user1@mail.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT t.accountingClerk, t.creationDate. u.windowsAccountName, t.customer, c.lastName,
       c.firstName, c.assignee 
FROM ticket as t 
LEFT JOIN customer AS c on t.customer = c.customerId 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON c.assignee = u.emailAdress 
WHERE c.assignee IS NOT NULL 
AND t.accountingClerk = (SELECT accountingClerk 
                         FROM tickets
                         WHERE creationDate = (SELECT MAX(creationDate) 
                                               FROM tickets)
                         ) AS Table1
GROUP BY t.customer;
```

The query might not be optimized, but i hope that it will work for you.